# Goodreads API and Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, api

I am trying to use [Goodreads API](https://www.goodreads.com/api) in a Django project. I have setup a simple tag to extract the reviews_widget and am attempting to send the css style and html to a template. However, the style and html is not being registered when sent. Using {{reviews_widget}} shows the style and html as a string, but {% load reviews_widget %} does not show anything.

book.html

```
{% extends "base.html"%}


{% block content %}

<!--  Does not render -->
  {% load reviews_widget %}

<!--  Shows response in string format -->
  {{ reviews_widget }}

 <!--  What is sent to template-->
<!--
<style> #goodreads-widget { font-family: georgia, serif; padding: 18px 0; width:565px; }
#goodreads-widget h1 { font-weight:normal; font-size: 16px; border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB596;
margin-bottom: 0; } #goodreads-widget a { text-decoration: none; color:#660; }
iframe{ background-color: #fff; } #goodreads-widget a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
#goodreads-widget a:active { color:#660; } #gr_footer { width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #BBB596;
text-align: right; } #goodreads-widget .gr_branding{ color: #382110; font-size: 11px;
text-decoration: none; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; } </style>
<div id="goodreads-widget"> <div id="gr_header"><h1><a href="https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/31430654-the-millionaire-booklet">
The Millionaire Booklet Reviews</a></h1></div> <iframe id="the_iframe"
src="https://www.goodreads.com/api/reviews_widget_iframe?did=DEVELOPER_ID&amp;format=html&amp;isbn=0990355454&amp;links=660&amp;min_rating=&amp;review_back=fff&amp;stars=000&amp;text=000"
width="565" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe> <div id="gr_footer"> <a class="gr_branding"
target="_blank" href="https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/31430654-the-millionaire-booklet?utm_medium=api&amp;utm_source=reviews_widget">
Reviews from Goodreads.com</a> </div> </div>
-->

{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from givegetapp.models import Give, Get, Reader

# For GoodReads Api
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.http import HttpRequest
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys
import requests

from django import template
register = template.Library()


try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
except ImportError:
    import urllib2

def book():


    isbn = '0990355454'

    key = 'devKEY' #replaced w/ dev key

    response = requests.get('https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn/'+isbn+'?key='+key)

    tree = ET.fromstring(response.content)

    reviews_widget = str

    for leaves in tree[1]:

        if leaves.tag == "reviews_widget":
            print(str(leaves.text))
            reviews_widget = str(leaves.text)

    return render(request, "book.html", {"reviews_widget": reviews_widget})
```

templatetags/reviews_widget.py

```
from django import template

# For GoodReads Api
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.http import HttpRequest
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys
import requests

from django import template
register = template.Library()


try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
except ImportError:
    import urllib2
# end of GoodReads


register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag()
def reviews_widget():
    isbn = '0990355454'

    key = 'g6mDefuBPg0ajE7c4Nwyg' #replace it with your developer key

    response = requests.get('https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn/'+isbn+'?key='+key)

    tree = ET.fromstring(response.content)

    reviews_widget = str

    for leaves in tree[1]:

        if leaves.tag == "reviews_widget":
            # print(str(leaves.text))
            reviews_widget = str(leaves.text)
    # print(reviews_widget)
    return {'reviews_widget': reviews_widget}
```

Since style needs to be in the head section, I figured I will have to split the response into different variables. How can I go about doing this? Also, how can the template treat the response as html and not as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Splitting**
You can do something like this:

```
first_part = response_html.split("</style>")[0] + "</style>"
second_part = response_html.split("</style>")[1]
```

And then have both first_part and second_part available as template context variables

```
return render(request, "book.html", {
    "style_section": first_part,
    "content_section": second_part,
    "reviews_widget": reviews_widget,
})
```

**Rendering as HTML rather than as string**
You can use mark_safe to get it to display as rendered HTML in the template. Consider carefully if you're able to do this as it could be a security risk if you don't trust the source of the data (GoodReads is a pretty safe bet, but its worth considering depending on how watertight your application needs to be)

```
<html>
    <head>
        {{ style_section|safe }}
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ content_section|safe }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good stuff. Thank you. Just to clarify, a simple_tag wouldn't be necessary. I can set the variables in views.py and send to templates.

Comment: Yepp! If you'd like to format the data with a template tag, that can be done as well. But if your view is splitting the response HTML exactly as you'd like it to be used inside the template, you don't need to: just tack on the |safe filter and it'll render as you'd expect.